# 301 Redirection for any url in my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a 301 redirection from myOldSite.com to myNewSite.com

I have this code in the htaccess in myOldSite.com

```
#Redirect 301 / https://myNewSite.com/myPage/
```

This works fine to redirect `myOldSite.com` but it does not work to fire the right redirection for `myOldSite.com/services.html`:

`myOldSite.com` is properly redirected to `myNewSite.com/myPage`

But

`myOldSite.com/services` is redirected to `myNewSite.com/myPage/services.html` **This is wrong.**

As you can see `services`is appended to the end. This is not what I need. I need:

`myOldSite.com/services` to be redirected to `myNewSite.com/myPage`

Any url which start with `myOldSite.com/ANYTHING_HERE` should be redirected to `myNewSite.com/myPage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch`

```
RedirectMatch 301 / https://myNewSite.com/myPage
```

This will not append the old URL subpath to the destination URL.

Comment: Not working in my end. Should I flush my DNS in my browser/computer?

Comment: @JPashs This should work. Try clearing your browser cache .